# Reading the results of SQLite SELECT query in Ionic2 v3.4

Tags: android, sqlite, typescript, ionic2

So I'm using the most recent version of Ionic2 (v3.4) and I'm trying to get the ionic native SQLite to work. I've been able to create database file and put a table in it like so:

```
this.sqlite.create({
  name: "data.db",
  location: "default"
})
.then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
  db.executeSql(tableQuery, {})
  .then(() => console.log("success"))
  .catch(() => console.log("fail"));
})
```

Inserting works too. But when I try to get the result of a selection:

```
this.sqlite.create({
  name: "data.db",
  location: "default"
})
.then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
  db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM savedCoupons where itemId=" + itemId, {})
  .then((db) => {console.log(JSON.stringify(db))})
  .catch(() => console.log("***ERROR WITH SELECT***"));
})
.catch(() => console.log("ERROR: FAILED TO CREATE/OPEN DATABASE."));
```

I get lost because of the lack of documentation. `JSON.stringify()` is being run so it would seem the query worked. It returns `{"rows":{"length":1}, "rowsAffected":0}` and that's it. How do I access the result of the query?

Comment: HI there, I have the same problem here, did get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Let you have three columns e.x id,name,lastname in your table.
after querying you can access it like:

```
  db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM student WHERE id='+1, {})
          .then(result => {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
               console.log("---Id---"+result.rows.item(i).id);
               console.log("---Name---"+result.rows.item(i).name);
               console.log("---Lastname---"+result.rows.item(i).lastname);
           }
          });
```